# Why does running awk on /etc/passwd gives nobody?

Tags: users

When I run the command `awk -F: '$3>999 {print $1}' /etc/passwd` I see this:

```
nobody
tim
askubuntu
```

Why is there a user called `nobody`? The only 2 user accounts I have are `tim` and `askubuntu`.

Comment: Nobody is one of system accounts

Comment: If you want to ignore that user you'd make it $3> 999 && $1~!/nobody/